# Помогите добиться правды RBAC Super Simple with Admin and User

Tags: php, yii2

Наткнулся на простой [пост с реализацией простой админки](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-prostaya-realizaciya-rbac-s-dvumya-rolyami.html#comment-10961). yii2 установлен advanced. Сделал все как описано, но, проблемы не прошли мимо. На выходе: если проверять статус по 10(STATUS_ACTIVE) - прекрасно логинит в bacend, если менять на 20(STATUS_ADMIN) - неверный логин или пароль! Мой код:
**commons\modelsUser.php**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ADMIN],
        ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED, self::STATUS_ADMIN]],
    ];
}

public static function isUserAdmin($username)
{
    return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
}
```

**common\models\LoginForm.php**

```
public function loginAdmin()
{
    if ($this->validate() && User::isUserAdmin($this->username)) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**backend\controllers\SiteController.php**

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->loginAdmin()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ну правильно, в БД то у тебя значение `status = 10` наверное

Comment: Не, не все так просто, не на столько я туплю что б не исправить в бд значение))) Я нашёл решение, немного позже опублкую...

Answer (score 0):

Решение быть может не самое правильное, но если делаем все просто - сойдет! В классе User (common\models\User.php) есть функция:

```
public static function findByUsername($username)
{
    return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
}
```

из-за вот этого параметра **'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]** наш код не мог пройти валидацию. Я просто его **удалил**.

Так же в этом контроллере **backend\controllers\SiteController.php** есть код при успешной авторизации:

```
return $this->goBack();
```

У меня он не работает, поэтому я заменил его на

```
return $this->render('index');
```

Вроде все нормально... Если кто-то знает как сделать лучше - **отпишите пожалуйста**, всегда рад новым знаниям!